# How do I return from a SetWebViewClient call?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android

I have a simple monodroid problem

Activity A calls Activity B

Activity B has a webview and looks like this

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.webView);
WebView webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
webView.LoadUrl(url);
webView.SetWebViewClient(new dealWithWebView());
```

In dealWithWebView(), I have this

```
class dealWithWebView : WebViewClient
{
    WebView webView;

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        webView = view;
        Context c = webView.Context;
        // it goes away and does something
        // calls another method in the class which returns back here
    }
}
```

Problem is that I don't seem to be able to get it to return back from the WebViewClient and then from "B" return back to "A".

How do I do this?

Comment: what do you mean by 'it goes away and does something'? You would use the `Finish()` method to close the webview activity, but I am not sure what you are trying to do. Please be more detailed...

Comment: Thanks. What I'm trying to do is in the OnPageFinished fire off a pile of things. Once they're done, control is passed back to activity "B" which calls Finish() and returns control to "A". Problem is you can't just put Finish() after the webView.SetWebViewClient(new dealWithWebView()); as this is called first (as the PageFinish isn't called until the page is finished), so what I'm trying to do is call Finish() in the SetWebViewClient. Obviously, if there is a better way, that would be good...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like

```
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.webView);
WebView webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;
webView.LoadUrl(url);
webView.SetWebViewClient(new dealWithWebView(this));
```

which uses:

```
class dealWithWebView : WebViewClient
{
    Activity parent;
    public dealWithWebView(Activity parent)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        var webView = view;
        Context c = webView.Context;
        // it goes away and does something
        // calls another method in the class which returns back here
        // all done - so finish the parent now
        parent.Finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
class WebViewClientCallback : WebViewClient
{
    public event EventHandler PageLoaded = delegate { };

    public override void OnPageFinished(WebView view, string url)
    {
        base.OnPageFinished(view, url);
        PageLoaded(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
clientCallback = new WebViewClientCallback();
clientCallback.PageLoaded += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    // What to do next?
    // Do the things you want to do after PageIsLoaded       
};
webview.SetWebViewClient(clientCallback);
webview.LoadData("<p>HTML-CONTENT</p>", "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```